# Configuração de Timeout para uma única chamada no Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

é possível configurar timeout para uma única classe de Controller específica no Spring Boot, como consigo fazer isso?
Pois utilizando a propriedade spring.session.timeout ela seta o timeout para a aplicação como um todo e não é este o objetivo.
Estou utilizando o Spring Boot 2. Pra deixar mais claro, preciso de algo equivalente a anotação @AccessTimeout do EJB,
só que voltado para o Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte anotação:

@Transactional(timeout = 200)

Pode ser tanto no Controller como um todo ou em um endpoint específico.